# Hangfire Enqueue background job using transaction

Tags: .net, hangfire

Does Hangfire support some kind of transaction management? Searching their documentation and Google, I'm not able to find anything. I would like to have a transaction making me able to first make my enqueued Handfire messages run, when my transaction / unit of work is done/completed/committed (e.g. after database transaction has been committed as well).

Just to illustrate my issue

```
using (var transaction =  new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
{
    backgroundJobClient.Enqueue(() => Console.WriteLine("Product created"));
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Committing transaction");
    transaction.Complete();
}
```

Running the above code, I would like the job to first be executed, when the transaction has been committed, but I see the `Product created` message right away, and after 1 second the `Committing transaction` appears.

*EDIT1*

I'm using Mongo storage and try to implement what suggested by @jbl. But the result is the same.

```
using (var transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
{
    var storage = new MongoStorage(mongoClient, "hangfire", new MongoStorageOptions());
    var backgroundJobClient = new BackgroundJobClient(storage);
    backgroundJobClient.Enqueue(() => Console.WriteLine("Product created"));
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Commiting transaction");
    transaction.Complete();
}
```

Comment: Maybe this can help : https://newreleases.io/project/github/HangfireIO/Hangfire/release/v1.2.1

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using the Mongo storage, but sure if thats any different. See my EDIT1.

Comment: What you want to achieve is not clear. Do you want the background job enqueueing to be part of the transaction ? Or do you want the enqueueing to happen obly if the transaction is successful ? (or do you want the transaction to be committed only if the background job processing is successful (I don't know if the last one can be achieved)

Comment: Yes, the first one, I would like the background jobs queuing to be part of the transaction.

Comment: I did this link: https://newreleases.io/project/github/HangfireIO/Hangfire/release/v1.2.1
but my problem was not solved, you don't have a better way

Answer (score -3):

What exactly are you trying to accomplish? If your goal is to process logic and commit something to your database in one transaction, then you don't need to use Hangfire (simply perform your changes and then commit). If your goal is process background logic outside of your current context, then you can let Hangfire handle the 'Fire and forget'-work.

Comment: This should be a comment